# Fit component to screen, No scrolling React-native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have two-component image and view I am trying to fit both to screen but its getting overflow and I don't want to implement scrollView.

The problem is Google sign in button is getting out of screen

Here's my approach

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                scrollEnabled={this.state.keyboardOpened}
            >
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white",flex:1}}>
                        <Image
                            style={{ width: "100%",height:200, backgroundColor: "white" }}
                            source={require('./assets/login.gif')}
                            resizeMode={"contain"}
                        />
                    </View>
                        <View>
                    {this.renderLoginDetails()}
                    </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Here's its result
[image]

Comment: get height of the device size and put some % of height to the Image containing view and remaining % of height to your loginDetails View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the height of your device screen.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

 <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
            resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            scrollEnabled={this.state.keyboardOpened}
            >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white",flex:1, height: windowHeight*0.04}}>
              <Image
                  style={{ width: "100%",height:200, backgroundColor: "white" }}
                  source={require('./assets/login.gif')}
                  resizeMode={"contain"}/>
       </View>
       <View style={{height: windowHeight*0.06}}>
             {this.renderLoginDetails()}
        </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: The renderLoginDetails component gets overlapped onto the image! Any Suggestions bro?

Comment: give Image, resizeMode : 'contain' @SukhiX07

Comment: yh DId stilll...

Comment: try giving flex to the image and the renderLoginDetails parent View

Comment: it worked with: marginTop:'auto'